# "Exit promise" with multiples fetch requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, fetch

I need to merge data from API. I do a first call to an endpoint that gives me a list of ids, then I do a request for each id. My goal is to return a list with the responses of all requests but I lost myself in promises ...

My code runs on NodeJS. Here is the code :

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const main = (req, res) => {
  fetch('ENDPOINT_THAT_GIVES_LIST_OF_IDS')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    parseIds(response)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    res.json(data)
    // I want data contains the list of responses
  })
})
.catch(error => console.error(error))
}

const getAdditionalInformations = async function(id) {
  let response = await fetch('CUSTOM_URL&q='+id, {
    method: 'GET',
  });
  response = await response.json();
  return response
}

const parseIds = (async raw_ids=> {
  let ids= []
  raw_ids.forEach(function(raw_id) {
    let informations = {
      // Object with data from the first request  
    }
    let additionalInformations = await 
getAdditionalInformations(raw_id['id'])
    let merged = {...informations, ...additionalInformations}
    ids.push(merged)
  })
  return ids
})

main()
```

I get this error : "await is only valid in async function" for this line :

```
let additionalInformations = await getAdditionalInformations(raw_id['id'])
```

Help me with promise and async/await please.

Comment: The callback in foreach is not async

Comment: Put an `async` before the `function(raw_id)` so that it looks like: `async function(raw_id)` :). That should at least make that await error go away.

Comment: Thanks, it removes the error but  I get an empty array at the end ... I've tried to print var on console and I get response from requests but the array still empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, just a slight bit of error here with your parentheses:

```
// notice the parentheses'
const parseIds = async (raw_ids) => {
  let ids= []
  raw_ids.forEach(function(raw_id) {
    let informations = {
      // Object with data from the first request  
    }
    let additionalInformations = await getAdditionalInformations(raw_id['id'])
    let merged = {...informations, ...additionalInformations}
    ids.push(merged)
  })
  return ids
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing an **async** after forEach

```js
const parseIds = (async raw_ids=> {
  let ids= []
  raw_ids.forEach(async function(raw_id) {
    let informations = {
      // Object with data from the first request  
    }
    let additionalInformations = await 
getAdditionalInformations(raw_id['id'])
    let merged = {...informations, ...additionalInformations}
    ids.push(merged)
  })
  return ids
})
```

One suggestion: you are mixing promises (.then()) with async/await. Prefer **async/await** is more readable.

Note that getAdditionalInformations inside forEach doesn't wait for it to be done before going to the next entry of the array.

You can use plain old for(var i=0; .... instead

Comment: Hey, this won't work - forEach doesn't know how to wait for its elements and the async inside the forEach won't wait for the contents of the promises created inside it. This needs to be a for... of loop or a .map with a Promise.all :]